# Select one of two html elements in a single marker using css selector with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get an element of an html code using css selector with jquery.
I show you a part of the code :

```
<th nowrap scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)" class="ms-vh2">
      <div Sortable="" SortDisable="" FilterDisable="" Filterable="" FilterDisableMessage="" name="LinkTitle" CTXNum="112" DisplayName="Type de matériel" FieldType="Computed" ResultType="" SortFields="View={69d1eb84-0c41-4f10-93d3-4a0c2e62a646}&SortField=LinkTitle&amp;SortDir=Asc" class="ms-vh-div">
             <a id="diidSortLinkTitle" onfocus="OnFocusFilter(this)" href="javascript: " onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" SortingFields="View={69d1eb84-0c41-4f10-93d3-4a0c2e62a646}&SortField=LinkTitle&amp;SortDir=Asc">
                 Type de matériel
                 <img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="Appuyez sur Maj+Entrée pour ouvrir le menu (nouvelle fenêtre)." />
             </a>
```

I want to have in a variable the value : "Type de matériel".

**With this selector :**

```
var elem_title="th.ms-vh2 div a#diidSortLinkTitle";
var COL=$(elem_title).html()
```

**I have COL =** `Type de matériel<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="Appuyez sur Maj+Entrée pour ouvrir le menu (nouvelle fenêtre).">`

Can you tell me how to keep "Type de matériel" without the `<img/>` element in my variable?

I've tried using .prev but I didn't succeed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text of the element, use `text()` instead of `html()`:

```
var COL = $(elem_title).text();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/a9vhz97h/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help